# Package the code into functions

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I use

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
(*=== 数据点  ===*)
bmiData = {17.53231562, 15.53238528, 17.26137457, 15.6088015, 
   15.20589021, 14.51292182, 14.75645275, 13.83305466, 15.69560048, 
   16.86902697, 18.0721242, 15.14403292, 17.44614778, 13.850415510, 
   18.32280354, 20.1631851, 18.59012493, 17.45527841, 18.58163511, 
   14.55731214, 15.40417624, 15.18792708, 15.62461325, 15.22882797, 
   15.02163115, 21.45492911, 20.89541272, 18.38647653, 29.34474265, 
   21.08535689, 22.02071132, 16.52876307, 18.38228254, 22.14403633, 
   19.2399927, 22.82261329, 26.10290031, 20.6759324, 22.34966855, 
   24.02533886};
fhlData = {1750, 2000, 2750, 2500, 2750, 2000, 2750, 1500, 2500, 2250,
    3000, 1250, 2750, 1750, 2250, 1750, 2000, 2250, 2750, 2000, 1750, 
   2250, 2750, 2500, 2000, 2772, 3458, 2065, 4208, 4579, 5300, 2811, 
   2563, 4075, 3762, 4781, 3919, 4357, 3839, 3770};

(*=== 基函数 ===*)
basisfun[n_] := Table[x^i, {i, 0, n}]

(*=== 数据点点图  ===*)
bmiListPlt = 
  ListPlot[bmiData, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"];
fhlListPlt = 
  ListPlot[fhlData, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"];

(*=== 数据点拟合 ===*)
bmifit = Fit[bmiData, basisfun@7, x];
fhlfit = Fit[fhlData, basisfun@7, x];

(*=== 拟合图像 ===*)
bmiFitPlt = Plot[
   bmifit,
   {x, 0, Length@bmiData + 1},
   PlotRange -> All
   ];

fhlFitPlt = Plot[
   fhlfit,
   {x, 0, Length@fhlData + 1},
   PlotRange -> All
   ];

(*=== 多项式拟合拟合和点图 ===*)
bmishow = Show[bmiFitPlt, bmiListPlt]
fhlshow = Show[fhlFitPlt, fhlListPlt]
```

get this
[image]

as you can see ,I had to go through the following steps

- get point data
- Constructing polynomial function
- Point plotted on a graph
- Do the fitting and draw the fitting curve
- Plot the fitting curve and data points on a graph

As you can see, I have two sets of data here, so I copy and paste a lot, in fact, I have many sets of data, so copying and pasting over and over again is obviously not a good idea.

Is there any way to package all of this into a function?

For example, if I input the **data of the points** and **the number of fits** I can draw the fit curve and the point graph directly

Comment: Since you can read Chinese, check this: https://note.youdao.com/ynoteshare/index.html?id=9e95f12fc7b90e8d4eb2ab9a09ae39c9&type=note&_time=1656768824709

Comment: @xzczd I will read it

Comment: You should read it right now. Also, relevant content can be easily found in the document: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html#22482

Comment: @xzczd The actual problem is so much more complicated than the help document that it feels useless

Comment: Then you don't really understand it. As stated in the document, and the first Chinese tutorial you haven't clicked so far, all you need is just `()` and `;`.

Comment: @xzczd I have reed it，The above example is too simple

Comment: Once again, you haven't really understood the document and the tutorial. 200 lines of code are not more complicated than 2 lines of code for defining a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

fit[data_?VectorQ, n : _Integer?NonNegative : 7, opts___] :=
 Module[
  {func = Fit[data, x^Range[0, n], x]},
  Show[
   Plot[Tooltip[func],
    {x, 0, Length@data + 1}],
   ListPlot[data,
    PlotStyle -> Red, 
    PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"],
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]], 
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> False,
   PlotRange -> All]]
```

Examples,

```
bmiData = {17.53231562, 15.53238528, 17.26137457, 15.6088015, 15.20589021, 
   14.51292182, 14.75645275, 13.83305466, 15.69560048, 16.86902697, 
   18.0721242, 15.14403292, 17.44614778, 13.850415510, 18.32280354, 
   20.1631851, 18.59012493, 17.45527841, 18.58163511, 14.55731214, 
   15.40417624, 15.18792708, 15.62461325, 15.22882797, 15.02163115, 
   21.45492911, 20.89541272, 18.38647653, 29.34474265, 21.08535689, 
   22.02071132, 16.52876307, 18.38228254, 22.14403633, 19.2399927, 
   22.82261329, 26.10290031, 20.6759324, 22.34966855, 24.02533886};

fit[bmiData, PlotLabel -> "bmiData"]
```

[image]

```
fhlData = {1750, 2000, 2750, 2500, 2750, 2000, 2750, 1500, 2500, 2250, 3000, 
   1250, 2750, 1750, 2250, 1750, 2000, 2250, 2750, 2000, 1750, 2250, 2750, 
   2500, 2000, 2772, 3458, 2065, 4208, 4579, 5300, 2811, 2563, 4075, 3762, 
   4781, 3919, 4357, 3839, 3770};

fit[fhlData, PlotLabel -> "fhlData"]
```

[image]

Comment: pretty good，I'm going to learn this code

Answer (score 5):

OK, since OP fails to understand the document and tutorial linked in the comment, I'll write an answer just to prove my statement:

**200 lines of code are not more complicated than 2 lines of code for defining a function. All you need is just `()` and `;`.** Oh, you already have `;`s, so you just need a pair of `()`.

```
函数[bmiData_, n_] := (
  (*===数据点点图===*)
  bmiListPlt = ListPlot[bmiData, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"];
  
  
  (*===数据点拟合===*)
  bmifit = Fit[bmiData, basisfun@n, x];
  
  (*===拟合图像===*)
  bmiFitPlt = Plot[bmifit, {x, 0, Length@bmiData + 1}, PlotRange -> All];
  
  
  (*===多项式拟合拟合和点图===*)
  bmishow = Show[bmiFitPlt, bmiListPlt]
  )
```

Definition of `basisfun` is the same as yours so omitted in this answer. Variable names are not modified, and are not localized with `Module`, etc., these aren't good habits of course. I don't modify them because they're not necessary. As mentioned above, all you need for defining a working function is just a pair of `()`. And it's my personal belief that a beginner should never try to pretend to be professional with `Module`, etc. if he doesn't really understand its usage.

Then the function can be used like

```
函数[bmiData, 7]

函数[fhlData, 7]
```

[image]

Now do you still feel it more complicated than the example in document?:

[image]

Comment: Magic function name. :)