# Extract coordinates from the Gaussian09 calculation file

Tags: string-manipulation, chemistry

```mathematica
text = " Deg. of freedom     1
 Full point group                 T       NOp  12
 Largest Abelian subgroup         D2      NOp   4
 Largest concise Abelian subgroup D2      NOp   4
                         Standard orientation:                         
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------\

 Center     Atomic      Atomic             Coordinates (Angstroms)
 Number     Number       Type             X           Y           Z
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------\

      1          6           0        0.000000    0.000000    0.\
000000
      2          1           0        0.617765    0.617765    0.\
617765
      3          1           0       -0.617765   \
-0.617765    0.617765
      4          1           0       -0.617765    0.617765   \
-0.617765
      5          1           0        0.617765   -0.617765   \
-0.617765
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------\

 Rotational constants (GHZ):    \
164.2463791    164.2463791    164.2463791
 Standard basis: 6-31G(d) (6D, 7F)
 There are     8 symmetry adapted cartesian basis functions of \
A   symmetry.
 There are     5 symmetry adapted cartesian basis functions of B1  \
symmetry.
 Old FWG=T    [O(C1),4C3(H1)]
 New FWG=TD   [O(C1),4C3(H1)]
 Largest Abelian subgroup         D2      NOp   4
 Largest concise Abelian subgroup D2      NOp   4
                         Standard orientation:                         
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------\

 Center     Atomic      Atomic             Coordinates (Angstroms)
 Number     Number       Type             X           Y           Z
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------\

      1          6           0        0.000000    0.000000    0.\
000000
      2          1           0        0.631339    0.631339    0.\
631339
      3          1           0       -0.631339   \
-0.631339    0.631339
      4          1           0       -0.631339    0.631339   \
-0.631339
      5          1           0        0.631339   -0.631339   \
-0.631339
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------\

 Rotational constants (GHZ):    \
157.2594345    157.2594345    157.2594345";
```

Here's a text,It is actually generated by the Gaussian09 calculation program. I have captured a small part here, and my goal is to extract the coordinates inside, as shown in the figure below

[image]

My idea is to take most of this out and look at it with "Standard orientation:" and "--"

[image]

```mathematica
str1 = "Standard orientation:";
str2 = "---------------------------------------------------------------------";
```

I tried to use the `StringCases` function to do it but I've done it many times and failed, and now I don't know how to do it, I don't know what match to do to match what I want, I can't think of so far

Comment: "I tried to use the `StringCases` function to do it but I've done it many times and failed. " `StringCases` is the correct function to use. How did you try? Please show us your trial so we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I couldn't find the right matching pattern, the matching failed, so here's what you think

Comment: Hint: `Shortest`.

Comment: FWIW, `Import` can handle direct importing from Gaussian log files https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GaussianLog.html ; the results go into a `Molecule` and you can extract the coordinates appropriately (if your goal is to extract coordinates rather than do text file processing)

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier I've used this before. It doesn't do much

Comment: "I've used this before. It doesn't do much." I'm not a user of Gaussian, but this is the third time I see similar statement under your question, and the previous two are proven to be wrong. (1. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/270271/1871 2. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275291/1871 ) Are you sure "it doesn't do much"? Can you elaborate a bit so @joshua and us can check if `Import` really "doesn't do much"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We first search the positions of the horizontal dashed lines:

```
pos = StringPosition[text, 
  "---------------------------------------------------------------------"];
```

Then we calculate the positions of the start and end of the 2 tables:

```
pos = {{pos[[2, 2]] + 2, pos[[3, 1]] - 2}, {pos[[5, 2]] + 2, pos[[6, 1]] - 2}};
```

Then we extract both tables:

```
text1 = StringTake[text, pos];
```

Now we import the tables:

```
tabs = (ImportString[#, "Table"] & /@ text1);
```

Finally we delete the superfluous port of the tables:

```
tabs = tabs[[All, All, 4 ;; 6]];
```

Now tabs contains the 2 tables:

```
TableForm[tabs[[1]]]
TableForm[tabs[[2]]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea

Comment: I tried it. I still have a lot of "-- "lines in my file. What should I do if I don't all match to the part that contains" Standard orientation "using this method

Comment: If you only want the tables starting with "Standard orientation", simply search positions of substring: "Standard orientation ......... -----------" that starts with "Standard orientation and ends as before". This gives starting positions of tables. The end position is the next ==---..---" line

Answer (score 3):

```
lines = StringSplit[text, "\n"];

 lines[[10 ;; 14]]  

{   1          6           0        0.000000    0.000000    0.000000,      
    2          1           0        0.617765    0.617765    0.617765,      
    3          1           0       -0.617765   -0.617765    0.617765,      
    4          1           0       -0.617765    0.617765   -0.617765,      
    5          1           0        0.617765   -0.617765   -0.617765}

streams = StringToStream /@ Lines[[10 ;; 14]];

ReadList[# , Number, 6] & /@ streams  

 {  {1,6,0,0.,0.,0.},
    {2,1,0,0.617765,0.617765,0.617765},
    {3,1,0,-0.617765,-0.617765,0.617765},
    {4,1,0,-0.617765,0.617765,-0.617765},
    {5,1,0,0.617765,-0.617765,-0.617765}}
```

Comment: I have to know what line it is, so for any output file, I don't know what line it is

Comment: Just do a search for a significant number by (StringPosition[ #,  "0.6177"  ]&)/@lines